# findAll() in BeautifulSoup skips over multiple ids

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I have a string with multiple ids in the image tag:

```
<img id="webfast-uhyubv" alt="" data-type="image" id="comp-jefxldtzbalatamediacontentimage" src="http://webfast.co/images/webfast-logo.png" /> 

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(webpage,"html.parser")
images = soup.findAll('img')
for image in images:
    print image
```

The above code only returns `id=comp-jefxldtzbalatamediacontentimage`

Replacing

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(webpage,"html.parser")
```

with

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(webpage,"lxml")
```

returns the first id webfast-uhyubv

However, I want to get both the id's in the order they exist for the input line.

Comment: this code only fetches first id and not the second one

Comment: @Rachit it depends on the parser.

Answer (score 1):

BeautifulSoup stores the [attributes of a tag in a dictionary](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes). Since a dictionary cannot have duplicate keys, one `id` attribute overwrites the other. You can check the dictionary of attributes using `tag.attrs`.

```
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(tag, 'html.parser')
>>> soup.img.attrs
{'id': 'comp-jefxldtzbalatamediacontentimage', 'alt': '', 'data-type': 'image', 'src': 'http://webfast.co/images/webfast-logo.png'}

>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(tag, 'lxml')
>>> soup.img.attrs
{'id': 'webfast-uhyubv', 'alt': '', 'data-type': 'image', 'src': 'http://webfast.co/images/webfast-logo.png'}
```

As you can see, we get different value for `id` using different parsers. This happens as [different parsers work differently](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers).

There is no way to get both the `id` values using BeautifulSoup. You can get them using RegEx. But, [**use it carefully and as a last resort!**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not)

```
>>> import re
>>> tag = '<img id="webfast-uhyubv" alt="" data-type="image" id="comp-jefxldtzbalatamediacontentimage" src="http://webfast.co/images/webfast-logo.png" />'
>>> ids = re.findall('id="(.*?)"', tag)
>>> ids
['webfast-uhyubv', 'comp-jefxldtzbalatamediacontentimage']
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. Given the HTML variants that exist, I'll be using the regex approach for now.